# Splitting large dataframe into smaller dataframes and then saving as csv

Tags: r, loops, filter, export-to-csv

First time posting on here - apologies if I have not yet got the hang of how to ask questions.

I have one large csv file ("AllANT_z") which contains data from over 330 participants, with around 290 rows of data per participant (over 100k rows in total). I have loaded in the large csv and now I am using a simple filter command to individually pick out participants (each participant has a unique participant ID, listed under a column titled 'participant'), save these as data, and then use the write.csv function to manually save them. Is there a way to loop this to make it faster? The method I am currently using works - but it is very time consuming and prone to human error. This is what I am using:

```
boa001 <- AllANT_z %>%
  filter(participant == "boa001")
write.csv(boa001, "E:/CognitiveData_Processed/ANT_zscored/zscored_allANT/boa001.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```

Any way to speed this up--with a loop maybe? I am an R newbie and do not yet have the know-how of how to loop. Any help would be much appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have 330 participants and they all follow the naming scheme 'boa{three-digit-number}'

```
#sprintf is used to generate the numbers with leading zeros
for(i in sprintf('%0.3d', 1:330)){

      participant <- paste0("boa", i)
      
      AllANT_z %>%
        filter(participant == participant) %>% 
        write.csv(paste0("E:/CognitiveData_Processed/ANT_zscored/zscored_allANT/", participant, ".csv", row.names = TRUE))
    }
```

This will generate the strings for all of them, select the corresponding participant, and write a CSV file with the corresponding name. If they don't follow a naming scheme, you should define a vector with all names like

```
participants <- c("boa001, ...")
```

and then iterate over it like

```
for(i in participants){
  AllANT_z %>%
    filter(participant == i) %>% 
    write.csv(paste0("E:/CognitiveData_Processed/ANT_zscored/zscored_allANT/", i, ".csv", row.names = TRUE))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions - both of these methods worked! It has saved me hours (I originally planned on doing this manually)!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all your participants as follows:

```
participant_list <- unique(AllANT_z$participant)
```

Note that I can't be sure if that works for you as I have not seen your actual data. But in general that should work. **Also you might want to check how many files there will be created**:

```
length(participant_list)
```

After that you can loop over the participant IDs, filter and save it to a CSV file:

```
for (id in participant_list) {
  participant_data <- AllANT_z %>%
    filter(participant == id)
  write.csv(participant_data, paste0("E:/CognitiveData_Processed/ANT_zscored/zscored_allANT/", id, ".csv"), row.names = TRUE)
}
```

You could also use subset instead of filter:

```
for (id in participant_list) {
  participant_data <- subset(AllANT_z, participant == id)
  write.csv(participant_data, paste0("E:/CognitiveData_Processed/ANT_zscored/zscored_allANT/", id, ".csv"), row.names = TRUE)
}
```